# emacs locks up under tmux when second user attaches to session

Tags: emacs, ssh, tmux, pair-programming

I recently started using the tmux/emacs combo and love it, but there's one thing I can't quite figure out.

My workflow typically starts on my desktop with sessions work and morning, with several emacs frames spread across seven tmux windows.

In the morning, I will ssh in from the laptop and attach to the morning session to read the news in emacs, which doesn't cause a.problem.

When I'm done reading, I switch to emacs in the working session, which cases emacs (but not tmux) to lock up; it won't respond to any keyboard events, including C-f and C-g.

I leave the working session open on my desktop at night, which seems to be the issue.

Has anyone else experienced and/or solved this issue?

I want to try pair programming once I get this figured out, so all help will be appreciated.

(I SSH in as the same user as I log in as on the desktop, if that matters, and I don't specify a socket when attaching to a tmux session.  Debian Squeeze, tmux 1.6, emacs 24.3.50.1, if it helps.)

Comment: I upgraded tmux to v1.9 yesterday and the problem persists.  I detached from the session last night and had no issues until I opened the session from both computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs` appears to fix the non-responsive issue.